# Use Hazelcast with Quarkus reactive

Tags: quarkus, hazelcast, vert.x, quarkus-reactive

I am try to integrate Reactive Quarkus application with Hazelcast for caching and to mange distributed data(because multiple pods can run). I created sample project. https://github.com/kavishkamk/hazelcast-quarkus-test. But I have to convert this code to handle with Reactive code. like say

```
import ......domain.Device;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheRepositoryBase;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class DeviceRepository implements PanacheRepositoryBase<Device, Integer> {

   private final HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;


   public DeviceRepository(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
         this.hazelcastInstance = hazelcastInstance;
   }

    // get device by device name
    public Uni<Device> getDeviceByDeviceRef(String deviceRef) {
        Map<String, Device> capitalcities = hazelcastInstance.getMap("device-map");

        // first check the cash
        return capitalcities.get(deviceRef)
              .ifNull().find("deviceRef", deviceRef).firstResult();
    }

}
```

this is not a valid code. but I think I have to use this kind of pattern or to use any kind of HazelcastInstance Async clinet. Can some one help me to solve this issue.

I also saw https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hazelcast/java/ vert.x instance. Do i have to use this kind of native pattern. I am using **implementation 'com.hazelcast:quarkus-hazelcast-client:4.0.0'** in my quarkus app. So I think there is a already available solution for this.

or is it safe to just call to get the response like this.

```
public Uni<Device> getDeviceByDeviceRef(String deviceRef) {
        Map<String, Person> capitalcities = hazelcastInstance.getMap("user-map1");
       Device device = capitalcities.get(deviceRef);

        if(device != null) {
           return Uni.createForm.item(device);
        }

        // first check the cash
        return find("deviceRef", deviceRef).firstResult();
    }
```

But this hazelcast cluster running as a container and call through the network.

```
docker run \
    -it \
    --network hazelcast-network \
    --rm \
    -e HZ_CLUSTERNAME=hello-world \
    -p 5701:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast:5.3.1
```

Thank you very much

**EDIT**

The problem is I assign the reserved map to java.util.Map instead of IMap. I i map there is a **CompletionStage** object. I include the test project link bellow. Thank you.

https://github.com/kavishkamk/hazelcast-quarkus-test/tree/java-embedded-instance